# AVAssetWriter rotate buffer for video orientation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter, cmsamplebuffer

I'm working on a live recording app in `Swift` using `AVFoundation` and I have an issue with the video orientation. I use `AVAssetWriter` and not `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` because I need to record in square format (correct me if I'm wrong).

I tried to use `videoInput.transform` but I heard that it is not supported in all video player.

I can't use `avcaptureconnection.videoOrientation` based on the device orientation because there is some "Main UI thread stop".

I read that the best solution is to rotate the `CMSampleBuffer` in the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` delegate function `captureOutput(...)`. It looks a bit complicated, the Apple's doc is not helping a lot and many posts are in `Objective-C`.

Before going that way, I would like to know if there are some solutions that I could have missed. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `AVAssetWriter`. Try,

```
  private let assetWriter: AVAssetWriter
  private var adaptor: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
```

And initialize `AVAssetWriter` like this,

```
adaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(rotationAngle: AVCaptureDevice.correctOrientation)
assetWriter = AVAssetWriter(input: adaptor.assetWriterInput)
```

Create an `extension` for `AVCaptureDevice`, Change the angles accordingly to rotate.

```
// The angle by which to rotate captured media, based on the current orientation, so that it looks correctly oriented to the user.
    var correctOrientation: CGFloat {
        let angle: CGFloat
        switch(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
         case .portraitUpsideDown: angle = -CGFloat.pi / 2 // Play around with these values
         case .landscapeLeft: angle = -CGFloat.pi
         case .landscapeRight: angle = 0
         case .portrait: angle = CGFloat.pi / 2
         default: angle = CGFloat.pi / 2
       }
       return angle
    }
```

Create another `extension` for `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`

```
extension AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor {
  convenience init(rotationAngle: CGFloat) {
    let input = AVAssetWriterInput(width: UIDevice.activeFormat.width, height: UIDevice.activeFormat.height)
    input.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)

    self.init(
      assetWriterInput: input,
      sourcePixelBufferAttributes: [
        kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, // use whatever format you used
        kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: UIDevice.activeFormat.width,
        kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: UIDevice.activeFormat.height])
  }
```